# Distributed search system JAVA

Tags: java, file, distributed-system

I want to create an offline distributed search system (later I'll use `sockets` and `multithreads`). 
For now, to begin, I'm saving the absolute paths of a specific directory(if I put C:\, il will be for the entire disk) into a file. What kind of file I should use? txt? I'm concerned about optimizing the system. (txt file of my 80GB partition has 34mb)

Later the user will use the system to search a specific file, I want search it on that file that I created previously.

if I used the `PrintWriter` with println, it will be hard to read that file later?

Thank you in advance. (I'll use this topic later to put some other questions if you don't mind.)

EDIT:

I used .txt and it worked fine with `PrintWriter`.

Comment: you mean to say that you are searching for a file from a specific path like if you want to search for a file `someDummyFile.avi` you have a search path described where to find that file?

Comment: The path of that file will be on a .txt create previously.

Comment: Hi,I found a nice framework to do this job, Apache Lucene (for java).

But..

1- Can I use this framework to build a distributed system? With multithread and sockets?

2- I'm forced to use the apache server?

3- There are any free book about this framework?